# reactJs my event.preventDefault(); doesnt work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i try to do a form on react js and i don't want to refresh the page when i submit my form.

I do a callback on my server (flask).

When i try to do :"event.preventDefault();" my call to my flask server doesn't work.

there is my code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';


const Form = (props) => {

  const componentDidMount = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();

    // Simple POST request with a JSON body using fetch
    
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ title: title })
    };
    
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/add', requestOptions)
    
        .then(response => response.json())
        
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
        
      
  }
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
  const [body, setBody] = useState('')


return (
     <div>
        <form onSubmit = {() => componentDidMount()} >

            <label htmlFor="title" className="form-label">Title</label>
                    <input 
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control" 
                    placeholder ="Enter title"
                    value={title}
                    onChange={(e)=>setTitle(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    />

                    <label htmlFor="body" className="form-label">Body</label>
                    <textarea 
                    className="form-control" 
                    placeholder ="Enter body" 
                    value={body}
                    onChange={(e)=>setBody(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    >
                    </textarea>

                    <button 
                    className="btn btn-primary mt-2"
                    >
                    Publish article</button>

                    </form>
    </div>
)}

export default Form;
```

I don't want to refresh the page cause one in two my callback function and i want to work on it but i can't read the error on the console.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are calling the function `componentDidMount` in `form` tag.

You just have to pass the `reference` of the function in the `onSubmit` attribute.

```
<form onSubmit={componentDidMount}>
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to pass event as well to trigger `event.preventDefault()` function

```
<form onSubmit = {(event) => componentDidMount(event)} >
```

Comment: Or `onSubmit={componentDidMount}`

Comment: Oh i did on my last try <form onSubmit = {(event) => componentDidMount()} >

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend to use a component lifecycle method (like componentDidMount) to handle a form submission event.
You could just create a specific handler:

```
const Form = (props) => {

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // ...
    }
    // ...


    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} > 

                {/* // ... */}
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, i just followed a tutorial to be honnest but i replaced it